# How can I use in method as a property class Object and use it. DART

Tags: flutter, dart, object, methods

```
class Hotel {
  static final Map<String, List<String>> mapInformation = {
    'Americana Hotel': [
      '4.3*', 
      '\$4000 / Night', 
    ],
  };

  String getPrice(String favouriteElementsName) {
    return mapInformation[favouriteElementsName]?.elementAt(1) ??
        'It may need fixes';
  }

  String getRating(String favouriteElementsName) {
    return mapInformation[favouriteElementsName]?.elementAt(0) ??
        'It may need fixes';
  }
}

class Home {
  static final Map<String, List<String>> mapInformation = {
    'Beachside Resort': [
      '2.2*', 
      '\$2200 / Night', 
    ],
  };

  String getPrice(String favouriteElementsName) {
    return mapInformation[favouriteElementsName]?.elementAt(1) ??
        'It may need fixes';
  }

  String getRating(String favouriteElementsName) {
    return mapInformation[favouriteElementsName]?.elementAt(0) ??
        'It may need fixes';
  }
}

class Favourite {
  final LinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> favouriteElementsInLinkedHashMap =
      LinkedHashMap();

  void changePrice(String favouriteElementKey, Object obj) {
    obj.mapInformation[favouriteElementKey]?[1] = '\$5000 / Night';
    var str1 = obj.getPrice(favouriteElementKey);
    var str2 = obj.getRating(favouriteElementKey);
  }

  void main() {
    var fav = Favourite();
    favouriteElementsInLinkedHashMap['Americana Hotel'] = Hotel;
    favouriteElementsInLinkedHashMap['Beachside Resort'] = Home;

    for (var mapKey in favouriteElementsInLinkedHashMap.keys) {
      fav.changePrice(
          mapKey, favouriteElementsInLinkedHashMap[mapKey]);
    }
  }
}
```

There is method changePrice, it gives me an error when i use mapInformation, is there any way, how can i use mapInformation, getPrice, getRating in method changePrice. There are a lot of classes as Hotel and Home. So I can't use if,else in method changePrice.

Answer (score 1):

Make an [abstract class](https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers#abstract) that defines those methods:

```
abstract class Accommodation {
  String getPrice(String favouriteElementsName);
  String getRating(String favouriteElementsName);
}
```

Now both `Hotel` and `Home` should extend that abstract class, and annotate the overriding methods with `@override`:

```dart
class Hotel extends Accommodation {
  @override
  String getPrice(String favouriteElementsName) {
    // ...
  }

  // Do the same for other overriding methods
}

class Home extends Accommodation {
  // Do the same as Hotel
}
```

Change the type of the `obj` parameter:

```dart
void changePrice(String favouriteElementKey, Accommodation obj) {
  // ...
}
```

---

Please note that you can't access `mapInformation` from `obj`, because `mapInformation` is a static field of the class. Preferably you should define another method inside the abstract class and implement it in the extending classes that modifies `mapInformation`.

---

There are also other Dart class modifiers that might suit for your case, see [Class modifiers](https://dart.dev/language/class-modifiers).

Answer (score 1):

You could use interface that in terms of dart is an abstract class e.g.

```
abstract class Establishment {
  Map<String, List<String>> get mapInformation;

  String getPrice(String favouriteElementsName);

  String getRating(String favouriteElementsName);
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
class Hotel implements Establishment {
  @override
  Map<String, List<String>> get mapInformation => {
        'Americana Hotel': [
          '4.3*',
          '\$4000 / Night',
        ],
      };

  @override
  String getPrice(String favouriteElementsName) =>
      mapInformation[favouriteElementsName]?.elementAt(1) ??
      'It may need fixes';

  @override
  String getRating(String favouriteElementsName) =>
      mapInformation[favouriteElementsName]?.elementAt(0) ??
      'It may need fixes';
}

class Home implements Establishment {
  @override
  Map<String, List<String>> get mapInformation => {
        'Beachside Resort': [
          '2.2*',
          '\$2200 / Night',
        ],
      };

  @override
  String getPrice(String favouriteElementsName) =>
      mapInformation[favouriteElementsName]?.elementAt(1) ??
      'It may need fixes';

  @override
  String getRating(String favouriteElementsName) =>
      mapInformation[favouriteElementsName]?.elementAt(0) ??
      'It may need fixes';
}
```

Finally, in the method changePrice you could use mapInformation:

```
class Favourite {
  final LinkedHashMap<String, dynamic> favouriteElementsInLinkedHashMap =
      LinkedHashMap();

  void changePrice(String favouriteElementKey, Establishment place) {
    place.mapInformation[favouriteElementKey]?[1] = '\$5000 / Night';
    final str1 = place.getPrice(favouriteElementKey);
    final str2 = place.getRating(favouriteElementKey);
  }

  void main() {
    final fav = Favourite();
    favouriteElementsInLinkedHashMap['Americana Hotel'] = Hotel;
    favouriteElementsInLinkedHashMap['Beachside Resort'] = Home;

    for (final mapKey in favouriteElementsInLinkedHashMap.keys) {
      fav.changePrice(mapKey, favouriteElementsInLinkedHashMap[mapKey]);
    }
  }
}
```

More info about Class modifiers [here](https://Class%20modifiers)